# How to modify config.xml when app is built with phonegap build

Tags: android, html, cordova

If I upload an app to PhoneGap and had it wrapped remotely, how and where do I access and modify the config.xml file? The PhoneGap api is vague and I would appreciate if someone can break the process down step-by-step

Answer (score 2):

You can locate config.xml xml folder in the res directory in the app considering you are building the project for android.

Comment: Where do I locate the res directory? All I have in the .zip are css,js, img files and the index.html.

Comment: In the zip u must be having a www folder. If you want to freshly make the build create a new project in android. Add cordova.jar and in the assets dir place www folder. You will find a res directory . If it doesn't contain xml folder you can create and copy your config.xml there

Comment: I've been using DreamWeaver to develop this app. So the wrap for android takes place on the PhoneGap server, not locally.

Comment: Haven't tried, but these links can help http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1046389 http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/connecting_dreamweaver_with_phonegap_build